# Where to find the Logged data in android device

Tags: android

I have loggged some message to identify the button click as given below.
Log.d(TAG, "Main Menu Button Clicked in Delivery");
When running the emulator i can find the logged message in the logcat using DDMS.

But the Problem is that in actual device where can i find this logged message.Is there any me need to find the loggged data.

Comment: If you want to store/retrieve logged data then i am sure IT's NOT POSSIBLE.

Answer (score 2):

That data is not registered in the device but flushed to the Logcat (the console, in Android terms). You can see the Logcat's output using eclipse and DDMS or executing 'adb logcat' in a shell (unix or windows).

Answer (score 0):

As Maragues mentioned above you can use adb logcat to view the log. However I absolutely recommend getting used to DDMS right away as you can search for your tag there, so you only get the log entries that has the tag you specified in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this app to see the logs in the devices. Just install this app in the device and browse.

Quick System Info PRO
https://market.android.com/details?id=org.uguess.android.sysinfo.pro&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy51Z3Vlc3MuYW5kcm9pZC5zeXNpbmZvLnBybyJd

Its very useful.

Regards,
SSuman185